# Android convert diamond question marks to UTF-8 Arabic string

Tags: java, android, utf-8

I'm using an [API](https://github.com/GideonLeGrange/mikrotik-java) that sends and receives raw bytes.

But i have problem with displaying the Arabic words that comes over the API, it's displaying like diamond question marks "���"

I've tried to convert the string from and to **utf-8**.

This example returns question marks but not inside the black square "??? ???" :

```
String str = new String(originalStr.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

This one returns empty string :

```
String str = new String(originalStr.getBytes("WINDOWS-1256"), "UTF-8");
```

And this one also returns an empty string :

```
String str = new String(originalStr.getBytes("WINDOWS-1252"), "UTF-8");
```

I've succeded to display the Arabic words in PHP by converting from **cp1256** to **utf-8** :

```
echo iconv('cp1256', 'utf-8', $string);
```

The correct character encoding for Arabic is **cp1256**

How can i achieve that?

Comment: What should the decoded output look like?

Comment: Normal arabic string, e.g : تجربة نص عربى

Comment: What is the output of the example given above? "���"

Comment: Sorry what do you mean the output? and what example? in the question (the diamond question marks) or in the comment i posted above?

Comment: ��� = "what in arabic"?

Comment: No, these three diamonds are an example, not a real string, unfortunetly i can't copy a text from my android app, can you explain why you need to know the question marks output?